# A map on degree $0$ from a complex of projectives to an acyclic complex extends uniquely to all degrees, up to homotopy

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_model#Projective_and_acyclic_complexes), it is stated:

> If $K$ is a complex of projectives in an abelian category and $L$ is an acyclic complex in that category, then any map $K_0 \to L_0$ extends to a chain map $ K\to L$, unique up to homotopy.

Do you know some reference for this result? Does it follow from other homological algebra results? (I'm currently working with results dealing with projective resolutions in an abelian category, I'm not familiarized with the aclyclic models theorem from the linked article).

Also: is this result really true? Or do we need some additional upper boundedness hypothesis for it to hold?

Answer (score 2):

It's not true as stated.

Let $K$ be the complex $\cdots\to0\to\mathbb{Z}\to0\to0\to\cdots$ of abelian groups, and let $L$ be the complex $\cdots\to0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\text{id}}\mathbb{Z}\to0\to\cdots$, both with their first nonzero term in degree zero. Then the identity map $K_0\to L_0$ does not extend to a chain map.

Maybe Wikipedia means that the complexes should be bounded to the right in degree zero.

Answer (score 1):

In the case when the complexes are bounded below (in the setting where the differential decrease degree), then this is essentially what is sometimes called the Fundamental Theorem of Homological Algebra. See https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-905-algebraic-topology-i-fall-2016/8ca6b03a5fc457714ed13e189a82f076_MIT18_905F16_lec22.pdf, for example. Those lecture notes give a direct proof: the theory of acyclic models is not necessary.